# How Can I Get Object in 'for in' Loop?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

```js
fetch('https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json')
  .then(Response => Response.json())
  .then(data => {
    for(const prop in data){
      console.log(prop)
      console.log(prop.statecode)  // undefined Why?, How can I access this?
     }
  })
```

Need Help,
`prop.statecode` show undefined Why? How can I access this?

Comment: `prop` is the key, not the object. You can use `data[prop]` to get the value/object

Comment: ^ Thus `data[prop].statecode` to access the state code of each value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For-each over an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prop` is a string here.

What you want is to use `prop` as the key in data to get hold of the object and access `statecode` from it.

```js
fetch('https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json')
  .then(Response => Response.json())
  .then(data => {
    for(const prop in data){
      console.log(prop)
      console.log(data[prop].statecode)  // undefined Why?, How can I access this?
     }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You should convert it to key-value pairs with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and iterate through the result with [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

```js
fetch("https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json")
  .then((Response) => Response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    //console.log(data)
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
      console.log(value.statecode)
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Object entries and the destruct your object in a way that `key` and `value` are clear.

```js
fetch('https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json')
  .then(Response => Response.json())
  .then(data => {
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      console.log(value.statecode)

    })
  })
```